# With Android new update I can't add SafeArg libraries

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

build.gradle (project) in the app. here before new version into

```
dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.4.0"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"}
```

-I could add. I can't add with the new update. Also in build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'}
```

I can't add. What should I do to use SafeArgs?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNJz8.jpg)

I need to use arguments of navigation. so ı need this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known incompatability](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#navigation_safe_args_compatibility) and there is no stable version of navigation that supports AGP 7.1.0 yet. In the meantime, you can use navigation 2.5.0-alpha01.